# Xcode ios tableview

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I'm using a tableview and I already found a tutorial online on how to add, edit or delete rows. Now I want to link every row to a default view where you can fill in data. For example: I click row 1, I come to a view with a text field and I fill in 1 and save it using Savestring1. Than I go back to the default view, I create a new row, click it, I get to the default view, fill in 2 and save it using Savestring2. Now how can I do this using 1 default view?

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UIAlertView * alertView= [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@" Enter Remark" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Submit", nil];


    alertView.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput;


   textfield=[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0];

   [alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeDefault;


    CGAffineTransform moveUp = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0.0, 0.0);

    [alertView setTransform: moveUp];

    [alertView show];


}
```

when you click on row then a alert-view comes up on screen with textfield 
declared textfield in .h viewcontroller

Answer (score 0):

using

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

You can create a viewController for viewing the data and for editing to and based on condition you can show that data from database and enter data into save view.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the object of the view where you fill in data and show that view in UITableViewDelegate method

   - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
2. Save the data in your preferred way(locally,plist, database, server etc.)
3. Return back to the default view once saved and load refreshed data in your tableview datasource and reload table.

Note: Using the same view can be achieved by loading the data from database in view mode with an option for edit and disabling the textfield. You can enable the textfield once user selects edit. And update the existing data once saved.